Where I can find Blender's tiles material?
I want to work with uv in my project using Blender's stock material - tiles with uv numbers. For that purpose I need to assign that material to object, but I don't know proper name for it and don't remember how to find it. Can somebody remind me, where is it located?

You can get the tile texture when you add an Image Texture node in the Shader Editor. Then click on the New button.

In the opening dialog box you can then choose the size of the image and if you want a Blank image which be filled with the chosen color or you can either choose the grey UV Grid or a Color Grid instead of Blank.

